# How to use setstate() in flutter to change the custompaint color at certain intervals inside a camera app?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I need to change color of the custompaint at certain intervals (like Timer.periodic) inside a camera app using foregroundpainter. How can I achieve it? I am able to print "timer" inside setstate() but color (r,g,b values) doesn't change.It appears that setstate() func gets processed (since I get "timer" printed) but custompaint doesn't change r,g,b values.

```
 import 'dart:async';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

 List<CameraDescription> cameras;

 Future<void> main() async {
 cameras = await availableCameras();
 runApp(CameraApp());
  }
 var temp;

 class CameraApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
   _CameraAppState createState() => _CameraAppState();
  }

   var r = 255;
   var g = 0;
   var b = 0;
   class _CameraAppState extends State<CameraApp> {
   CameraController controller;

 var crossPainter = CrossPainter(r, g, b);
 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   controller = CameraController(cameras[0], 
    ResolutionPreset.medium);
   controller.initialize().then((_) {
    if (!mounted) {
     return;
       }
  setState(() {
  Timer(new Duration(seconds: 5), () {
        r = 0;
        g = 255;
        b = 0;
        print('timer');
        crossPainter = CrossPainter(r, g, b);

      });

      });
      });
      }

    @override
     void dispose() {
        controller?.dispose();
        super.dispose();
         }


        var t = Timer.periodic(new Duration(milliseconds: 500), 
    (Timer timer)=>  CrossPainter(225,0,0));

  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
        }



   return  CustomPaint(
       //foregroundPainter: CrossPainter(r, g, b),

       foregroundPainter:crossPainter,
          size:Size(100, 100),
       willChange:true,
            child: CameraPreview(controller));

      }
     }

   class CrossPainter extends CustomPainter{

     @override

     Paint _paint;
      CrossPainter(r,g,b){

      _paint = Paint()
      ..color = Color.fromRGBO(r,g,b,1)
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;


         }

     @override
     void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {

     var rect = Offset(100,0.0) & size;

     canvas.drawRect(rect, _paint);

       }


      @override
     bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {

      return true;
       }

       }
```

Comment: Can you check if the widget is mounted inside your setstate, https://flutterbyexample.com/stateful-widget-lifecycle/#2-mounted-is-true and see if that makes any difference

Comment: `bool mount = this.mounted;
  print(mount);  //true` 
it prints true, any other answer?

Comment: I meant, something like  
       loadData() async {
    final location = await Location.fetchByID(this.locationID);

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        this.location = location;
      });
    }
  }

Comment: unable to use the above mentioned code, I get locationID is not defined, can you be elaborate what we need to find?

Comment: Sorry location id is just example, you can use your code, not really sure otherwise what's going on